# c# list<int> how to insert a new value in between two values

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

so i have a list where i need to add new values constantly but when i do i need to increment it and insert it in between two values.

```
List<int> initializers = new List <int>();

initializers.Add(1);
initializers.Add(3);
```

so initializers would have 1, 3 values.

i would then process a new set of numbers. the initializers will need to have the values.

1, 5, 3, 7

and if i process another set of numbers it should become

1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15

i know how to properly generate the new values inserted, i just need some help on inserting it in between the existing values of the initializers without having to add 2 or 3 more loops to move the values' positions.

Comment: Please read documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Or even search - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460223/whats-a-good-way-to-insert-something-in-the-middle-of-a-list, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462518/short-way-to-add-item-after-item-in-list or ...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
List<int> initializers = new List <int>();

initializers.Add(1);
initializers.Add(3);

int index = initializers.IndexOf(3);
initializers.Insert(index, 2);
```

Gives you 1,2,3.

Comment: Thanks! But what if you don't know if there is a '3' in the list or not? (I just want to add my list item at index 0 no matter what else is in the list)

Comment: You can check if there is a 3 by using Count() and Any()

Answer (score 21):

Use [`List<T>.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx):

```
initializers.Insert(index, value);
```

Comment: i see. i didn't know this existed. lol. new with c#. thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

For those who are looking for something more complex (*inserting more than one item between 2 values, or don't know how to find the `index` of an item in a list*), here is the answer:

Insert one item between 2 values is dead easy, as already mentioned by others:

```
myList.Insert(index, newItem);
```

Insert more than one item also is easy, thanks to [`InsertRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insertrange) method:

```
myList.InsertRange(index, newItems);
```

And finally using following code you can find the index of an item in list:

```
var index = myList.FindIndex(x => x.Whatever == whatever); // e.g x.Id == id
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [List.Insert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) instead of List.Add() to insert items at a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if there is a computationally viable way of sorting the elements, is:

```
list.Insert(num);
// ...
list.Insert(otherNum);

// Sorting function. Let's sort by absolute value
list.Sort((x, y) => return Math.Abs(x) - Math.Abs(y));
```