# How to move everything up one spot in an array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I'm trying to make a method that moves every character in between the first and last character in an array up one spot. Also, the first to last character has to 'move' to the second spot in the array ([1]). in short, I want 'abcdef' to become 'aebcdf'.
This is what I came up with:

```
                if (myArray.Length > 3)
            {
                char savechar = myArray[myArray.Length - 2];
                for (int t = 1; t < (myArray.Length - 2); t++)
                {
                    myArray[t++] = myArray[t];
                }
                myArray[1] = savechar;
            }
```

Problem here is, it just moves the second character to the end, instead of moving all characters up one spot. (I know why it does that, I just don't know how I can fix this)
Someone help?

Comment: do you obliged to use character shifting with for loop? or can you use LINQ query?

Comment: Sounds like you need to swap the two characters, not just assign

Comment: If possible, I'd like to use a for loop, yes. I just started programming, haven't heard of LINQ yet...

Comment: What you are going to want to do is reach inside the array, pull out "the first to last character" (which seems to be the "second last" one), put it in a variable for later.  Then loop, from the back to the front, (skipping the last character and the first character) and copying the (n-1) character into the (n) spot.  When you are finished, plunk that second last character you put aside into the second spot.  Don't forget that everything is 0-based (which works very well when looping from 0 to n-1, but is very weird in the other direction.

Comment: Store the second-last element (element n-1; `e`) in a temp variable. Use a single call of  `Array.Copy` to move the elements 1,...,n-2. Place the element in the temp variable in array slot #1. Done...

Comment: I recommend that beginner programmers solve this problem on paper first; actually get a piece of paper and a pencil and an eraser, write out the array on the page, and then simulate the operations you need to perform. **Carefully write down every little step you do along the way**, and then carefully translate that algorithm into code.

Comment: Also: **break yourself of the habit of using ++ inside another expression right now**.  It does nothing for you except make your algorithm harder to understand and harder to get right.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @EricLippert :)

Comment: Does the variable need to be an array? If you plan to move elements around like this, you might be better off using a `List<char>` which will shift the other elements when you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110872/c-sharp-listint-how-to-insert-a-new-value-in-between-two-values) or [remove](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2). Or use a temp list and [convert it back to an array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2) after you're done moving things.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start from the end rather than the start so that you don't copy over characters that you already changed.
2. I don't think you intended to use "++" inside your loop. This changes the value of t and is not needed.

Here is the resulting code:

```
if (myArray.Length > 3)
{
    char savechar = myArray[myArray.Length - 2];
    for (int t = myArray.Length - 2; t > 1; t--)
    {
        myArray[t] = myArray[t-1];
    }
    myArray[1] = savechar;
}
```

Comment: @meilelhorst: This is exactly what I described in my comment.  See if you can figure out how to do this from the comment without looking at this code.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you both! I was wondering if going from back to front would make a difference, and I'm happy to see it does. I will try to re-write the code a couple of times myself so I can understand it better ;)

Comment: @MielElhorst: If you follow Eric Lippert's advice (to do it first on paper), you will see that the way to make this work (on paper) is to start at the end and work backwards.  If you start at the beginning, you have don't have any "empty slots" to put your newly moved character, whereas, if you start at the end, you can move it into the most recently vacated spot.

Answer (score 2):

This gives the required result. Note that there are no length checks since I'm using your sample input. And no effort to make it efficient ;)

```
var list = "abcdef".ToCharArray().ToList();    
var item = list.ElementAt(list.Count - 2);
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 2);
list.Insert(1, item);
var reordered = string.Join(string.Empty, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
for (int i = 1; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
{
  var temp = input[i];
  input[i] = input[input.Length - 2];
  input[input.Length - 2] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Array.Copy:

```
if (myArray.Length > 3)
{
    char savechar = myArray[myArray.Length - 2];
    Array.Copy(myArray, 1, myArray, 2, myArray.Length - 3);
    myArray[1] = savechar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work only for strings, but it works:

```
    var text = "abcdef";
    var shifted = text.First() + text.Substring(text.Length - 2, 1) + text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2) + text.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an universal algorytm to cycle shift `array` by `shiftCount` elements and skip `skippedElements` at the start and at the end of `array`:

```
var array = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

var skippedElements = 1;
var shiftCount = 1;
bool shiftLeft = true;
if (shiftLeft)
{
    // shift left
    Array.Reverse(array, skippedElements, shiftCount);
    Array.Reverse(array, skippedElements + shiftCount, array.Length - skippedElements * 2 - shiftCount);
    Array.Reverse(array, skippedElements, array.Length - skippedElements - shiftCount);

}
else
{
    // shift right
    Array.Reverse(array, skippedElements, array.Length - skippedElements * 2);
    Array.Reverse(array, skippedElements + shiftCount,  array.Length - skippedElements * 2 - shiftCount);
    Array.Reverse(array, skippedElements, shiftCount);
}
```

It's modification for [Reversal algorithm for array rotation](https://thejeshvenkata.github.io/HTMLPages/program-for-array-rotation-continued-reversal-algorithm.html). It works for `skippedElements > 0`. it does not require additional variables or memory.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd probably go with [NPCampbell's `Array.Copy` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335098/1715579) if this were a production system, but for the sake of demonstration (and just a little code-golf fun) here's a solution using Linq:

```
var n = myArray.Length - 1;
var newArray = myArray.Select((_, i) => myArray[i % n > 0 ? (i > 1 ? i : n) - 1 : i]).ToArray();
```

It's not the most performant option and definitely not the very readable, but it works.